# Using JDBC to Write a Query

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I am working with JDBC and PostgreSQL and I have to do the following:

```
/*
 * Return list of film titles whose length is equal to or greater
 * than the minimum length, and less than or equal to the maximum
 * length.
 */
public List<String> getFilmTitlesBasedOnLengthRange(Connection connection,
                int minLength, int maxLength) {
        List<String> result = new LinkedList<String>();

        return result;
}
```

I tried to first solve this problem by writing a query in PostgreSQL (not sure if it's even correct):

```
SELECT title
FROM dv_film A, dv_film B
WHERE (A.length >= (COUNT(length) ASC LIMIT 1)) AND (B.length >= (COUNT(length) DESC LIMIT 1));
```

The dv_film relation is:

```
CREATE TABLE dv_film (
    film_id      integer, 
    title        varchar(50), 
    description  text, 
    length       smallint, 
    rating       mpaa_rating
);
```

My attempt at trying to solve the problem is:

```
public List<String> getFilmTitlesBasedOnLengthRange(Connection connection,
                        int minLength, int maxLength) {
                List<String> result = new LinkedList<String>();

                PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT title FROM dv_film A, dv_film B WHERE (? >= (COUNT(length) ASC LIMIT 1)) AND (? >= (COUNT(length) DESC LIMIT 1));");

                return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

your statement:

```
PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT title FROM dv_film A, dv_film B WHERE (? >= (COUNT(length) ASC LIMIT 1)) AND (? >= (COUNT(length) DESC LIMIT 1));");
```

Here you are trying to pass column names to PreparedStatement and **you cannot set column names as PreparedStatement values.** You can only set
column values as PreparedStatement values